# jQuery Select/Dropdown Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a selector for all selects (dropdowns)?

I don't see it [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Cleanest I've come up with is:

```
$(":input").has("option")
```

`$(":text")` gets textboxes & textareas, `$(":button")` gets buttons, `$(":radio")` gets radio buttons, `$(":checkbox")` gets checkboxes...

Where's `$(":select")`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dude. You're thinking **way too hard** about this:

```
$('select')
```

The *only* reason that jQuery provides pseudo-selectors for the other input element types is that there is more than one possible tag for each such type (e.g. `<input type="button">` and `<button>` for `:button`) but **there is only the `<select>` tag for dropdowns.**